# How to stop the size of frame becomes 1024x768 in Swift playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

The frame of the main view in UIViewController becomes 1024x768.

At first, the problem is not obvious, but later when doing layout, it becomes troublesome.
How can I make sure the frame stays the same size as what I set with .preferredContentSize ?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.frame //When run playground shows 1024x768
    }
}
let viewController = MyViewController()
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 667) // set to different size


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Comment: just change the frame: `viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-layout has not finished in `viewDidAppear()`.

You can get the frame size in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, both of which are called more than once - but the last call *will* have the correct frame size.

You can also get it in `viewDidAppear` but that may be too late for your needs.

A common approach is to create a `var` holding the initial size, and then run any code which needs the actual frame size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` ***if*** the current frame size is different from the saved size (and the updating the saved size).